# How to specify a time duration in Boost Semaphore

Tags: c++, boost

I'm attempting to use the `timed_wait` function in `boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore`.

```
bool timed_wait(const boost::posix_time::ptime & abs_time)
```

In all of the Boost documentation and Stack Overflow questions that I've researched, there doesn't appear to be a single straightforward example on how to use timed_wait for a simple duration like 5 seconds. I can't figure out how to initialize a boost::posix_time::ptime object that specifies a time duration.

The closest I've gotten is the following, which appears to immediately timeout instead of timeout after 5 seconds:

```
while (true)
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime wait_time(boost::interprocess::microsec_clock::local_time());
    wait_time = wait_time + boost::posix_time::microseconds(5000000);

    printf("thread 1 wait\n");
    bool result = binary_sem.timed_wait(wait_time);
    if (result == true)
    {
        printf("thread 1 acquire\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("timeout\n");
    }
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not so sure, if the `boost::posix_time` supports microseconds well at all. It was limited to milliseconds IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ an example using milliseconds would be great!

Comment: Isn't there one in the boost docs?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wasn't able to find a straightforward example of timed_wait using any resolution. Similarly, I could not find an example of specifying a boost::posix_time::ptime that is a simple duration, e.g. 5000 milliseconds.

Comment: Well, the [posix_time docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/date_time/doc/class_time_duration.html) seem to be a bit old. Though it simply should be `boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000)` in your code, no?

Comment: See my answer, there are many time divisions under` boost::posix_time`, see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#time_duration_count_constr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the base should be UTC:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dd9c706edb82d49)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_semaphore.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace pt = boost::posix_time;

int main() {
    using clock = boost::interprocess::microsec_clock;
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore sem(3);

    auto deadline = clock::universal_time() + pt::seconds(5);

    for (auto i : {1,2,3,4})
        std::cout << "#" << i << " acquired? " << sem.timed_wait(deadline) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
#1 acquired? 1
#2 acquired? 1
#3 acquired? 1
#4 acquired? 0

real    0m5,005s
user    0m0,001s
sys     0m0,004s
```